# Populate private member of the class outside the class

Tags: c#

I have the following class :

```
public class MyFragment
{
  /// members + methods
  void proc();
}
public class MyProc
{
    /// members + methods

}
public class MyClass
{
   private MyProc m_proc;
   private MyFragment m_frag;
   public MyClass(MyFragment fr)
   {
       m_proc = new MyProc();
       m_frag = new MyFrag();
       m_frag.proc();
   }
}
```

For the method `void proc()` of class `MyFragment` I can not change not signature ,nor return type. But can change the implementation
My goal is to update `m_proc` of `MyClass` with some data generated inside `MyFragment::proc()`
I thought about :

Generate inside `MyFragment` ,the object from `MyProc` class, populate it in the `MyFragment::proc()`
and after that copy it to `MyClass.m_proc`.
On the other hand I don`t like to much the idea of copying...how can it be done more effectively

Comment: What part of the word "private" do you not understand?

Comment: Yakov, what programming language are you writing this in? The code looks like C# (`public class`) but `MyFragment::proc()` looks like C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can write another method, which accepts `MyProc` as argument, and call this method from `proc`:

```
public class MyFragment
{
    /// members + methods
    public void proc() 
    {
        // just pass dummy argument
        ProcEx(new MyProc());
    }

    public void ProcEx(MyProc myProc)
    {
       // fill myProc
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
   private MyProc m_proc;
   private MyFragment m_frag;
   public MyClass(MyFragment fr)
   {
       m_proc = new MyProc();
       m_frag = new MyFrag();
       m_frag.ProcEx(m_proc);
   }
}
```

P.S. CPP-styled member names drives me crazy.